# How to get the value of particular attribute from a JSON using RestAssured.JsonPath

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, rest-assured, jsonpath

I'm trying to hit an API thru RestAssured + Java code and able to get some response as you can see in this post. But I need to get the value of particular node / attribute i.e. **errorParams** which is present in the JSON and print in the Java Console.

```
{
   "customerId":null,
   "errorDetails":[
      [
         {
            "errorCode":"ABC_2021",
            "errorParams":"Input Customer Id"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

I tried like this and not working.

```
JsonPath jsp = new JsonPath(response.getBody().asString());

System.out.println(jsp.getString("errorDetails.errorParams"));

System.out.println(jsp.getString("$['errorDetails']['errorParams']"));
```

Any suggestions or working script would be helpful for me.

Thanks, 
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: You need to handle arrays, try: `$.errorDetails[*][*].errorParams`

Answer (score 0):

That one works just fine:

`System.out.println(jsp.getString("errorDetails.errorParams"));`

So I assumed you retrieving your JsonPath in the wrong way, try:

```
JsonPath jsp = response.jsonPath();
```

or

```
JsonPath jsp = new JsonPath(response.asString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following snippet it works for me

```
System.out.println(response.jsonPath().getString("errorDetails.errorParams"));
```